# MVC5 Attribute based routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

So this is my code:

**Controller.cs**

```
[Route("{controller}/{slug}")]
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string slug)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Tv tv = db.Tv.Find(id);
        if (tv == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tv);
    }
```

***{slug} being a title.* however my URL is showing**

```
{controller}/{slug}?id=4
```

Now I do have to pass the Id to the controller so I can find the record in the database but I dont want it in the URL.

**How can I remove the Id?**

Comment: If you want the `id` accessible in this method, it has to come in as a parameter _somehow_. Since this is presumably a `GET` method, then having it in the URL makes sense. Can you provide an example of what you would like the URL to look like? Maybe you want the `id` as part of the path, as in `/Details/some-title/54`?

Comment: So `/Details/54` would be the original path. However I want the URL to look like {controller}/{slug}. I need the Id in the controller but don't want it in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All get parameters have to be in the URL.  The only other way is to add the ID as a header, and extract it from the headers collection.  It would be up to the client to pass this value through the header, and your API to enforce an ID as a header variable.  That is the ONLY way around this, as you have to pass the ID somehow.

Alternatively, if title's are unique,  use that to look up the ID within the controller.

EDIT: Another alternative, you can use a FORM POST and put the ID in the form.  You can style a button to look like a link.

Comment: So from my Index page I have a link like this `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.TvID, slug=item.TvTitle })`

Comment: I don't believe you can from an actionlink

Comment: Also I have tried using Titles to look for instead of Id however it fails.

Comment: One alternative above is to dump the link, and use a form.  See my edit.

Comment: Would the Title have to be a [Key] in order to find it?

Comment: There is no automatic process that does this.  What I mean is you would have to write code to convert the title to a key, by doing a select query.  This only works if title is guaranteed unique.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I believe I have solved this while still keeping the GET method instead of using POST.

My Model class has 2 keys. Normally you will need to pass both keys to the controller, however using the code below allows me to only send one key.This means I can avoid the ID being in the URL and still having it as a key in the Model.

```
    [Route("TvShows/{slug}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string slug)
    {
        if (slug == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Tv tv = db.Tv.Where(x => x.TvTitle == slug).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tv == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tv);
    }
```